# ¿Como puedo enviarle a un control de usuario personalizado (custom) el alto de un botón (padre)?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol, ivalueconverter

me explico lo que quiero conseguir, yo tengo un control de usuario personalizado, que esta dentro de un botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa imagen esta el botón que se puede ver por el recuadro azul, el elemento que esta dentro es un UC, pues bien mi idea es con una función conversora ajustar el tamaño de la imagen usando el alto del botón, el alto del botón se define en tiempo de ejecución ya que esta en una rejilla con el alto proporcional es decir `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`

y ahí esta donde me atasco, he probado 2 formas diferentes, ambas fallan.

1ª enviando el alto al UC mediante propiedades, Visual Studio me indica un error, diciendo que no puedo usar bind para enviar el valor de una propiedad.

Como por ejemplo en el UC propiedad double AltoBoton y luego en código

```
AltoBoton = "{Bind ElementName BotonDetalles, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

2ª En vez de con una propiedad, tratar de encontrar el ancestro botón y mandar a la clase conversora el valor del alto actual de botón o de cualquier otro elemento.

También falla, he probado con todas las combinaciones posibles haciendo un binding al alto de la imagen
`Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImagenAdaptativa}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualHeight}"`, respecto al borde, al botón, al stackpanel etc, el problema es que hay 2 situaciones posibles con esto:

1º Se fija en algún stackpanel o similar que no tiene tamaño fijo, entra en un bucle infinito
2º Llega al botón deseado pero sigue buscando ancestros y termina encontrando uno con la situación anterior.

Resultado o no termina nunca o se vuelve loco calculando la altura.

y sincera y honestamente ya no se que hacer, muestro el código relativo al UC

UC

```
<UserControl x:Class="ElEscribaDelDJ.Resources.UserControls.CampaignResources.ElementoRecursos"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ElEscribaDelDJ.Resources.UserControls.CampaignResources"
             xmlns:imagenadaptativa = "clr-namespace:ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.Utilidades.Conversores"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <imagenadaptativa:ImagenAdaptativa x:Key="ImagenAdaptativa"/>
        <Style x:Key="ElementoRecursos" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <!-- Elemento del menu, compuesto de un botón con un stackpanel para que contenga una imagen y texto pulsable
            Así mismo, contendra el panel que distribuye la lista con todos los documentos de campaña, escenario y aventuras y el botón añadir-->
        <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource ElementoRecursos}">
            <!-- boton con dos partes, puesta en horizontal, una imagen y texto -->
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding DireccionImagen}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImagenAdaptativa}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NombreElemento}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>


            <StackPanel Background="White">
                
            </StackPanel>


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

La parte de MenuRecursos donde se le llama

```
<StackPanel x:Name="PrimeraColumna">
                <Button x:Name="BotonDetallesDocumentos" 
                    Click="BotonDetallesDocumentos_Click" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <uc:ElementoRecursos DireccionImagen="/images/icons/icons8-documents.png" 
                                 NombreElemento="Archivos/Documentos"/>
            </Button>
            <!-- Control de usuario que controla titulo de campaña y el botón para crear uno nuevo -->
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerDocumentos" 
                              Visibility="Collapsed"
                              MaxHeight="{Binding MaximaAlturaScrollViewers}">

                    <StackPanel>
                        <uc:SeccionConBoton Seccion="Campaña" Background="White"/>
                        <WrapPanel x:Name="WrapPanelDetallesDocumentos" 
                           Background="#f9f2a4">
                            
                        <!-- Control de usuario que muestra los detalles de cada archivo y permite eliminarlo -->
                            <uc:DetallesArchivoCampana NombreArchivo="Manual basico ejemplo" 
                                                   DireccionArchivo="C:\Usuarios\David\Escritorio\Rol\Warhammer\Manuales" 
                                                   UrlArchivo="http:\\www.google.es\drive\manolito\manualbasico234242242?=ver.html"
                                                       Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <uc:DetallesArchivoCampana NombreArchivo="Manual basico ejemplo" 
                                                   DireccionArchivo="C:\Usuarios\David\Escritorio\Rol\Warhammer\Manuales" 
                                                   UrlArchivo="http:\\www.google.es\drive\manolito\manualbasico234242242?=ver.html"
                                                       Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <uc:DetallesArchivoCampana NombreArchivo="Manual basico ejemplo" 
                                                   DireccionArchivo="C:\Usuarios\David\Escritorio\Rol\Warhammer\Manuales" 
                                                   UrlArchivo="http:\\www.google.es\drive\manolito\manualbasico234242242?=ver.html"
                                                       Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <uc:DetallesArchivoCampana NombreArchivo="Manual basico ejemplo" 
                                                   DireccionArchivo="C:\Usuarios\David\Escritorio\Rol\Warhammer\Manuales" 
                                                   UrlArchivo="http:\\www.google.es\drive\manolito\manualbasico234242242?=ver.html"
                                                       Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
```

Por último la función conversora

```
namespace ElEscribaDelDJ.Classes.Utilidades.Conversores
{
    class ImagenAdaptativa : IValueConverter
    {

        //Este conversor obtiene como primer valor en value el porcentaje, como segundo valor en parameter el ancho del elemento padre
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double porcentaje = (double)value;
            return porcentaje * 0.8;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que la Imagen, en el UC, deberías dejarla con alto y ancho automático en vez de aplicarle un Binding ya que esto da problemas, solo quítale esos atributos y en vez de eso juega con el Stretch para que se estire y de ese modo se adapte por si misma al alto y ancho de su contenedor. Por otra parte creo que estás complicándote de la vida haciendo UserControls, puedes perfectamente hacer toda esa plantilla directo en el botón y bindear valores directamente.

Comment: Acabo de probar con todos los tipos de stretch, la imagen no modifica su tamaño, simplemente ignora el stretch no se porque, respecto a la 2ª parte si podría meter todo en el botón, pero la idea precisamente de tener un UC es tener algo reusable que me simplifica mucho la vida, y me permite tener las cosas separadas y faciles de modificar porque luego estos botones al usarlos tienen funcionalidades propias, entonces en vez de tener un montón de lineas repetidas y un xaml enorme, me permite tenerlo más pequeño, legible y fácil de mantener.

Comment: En Image del UC, VerticalAlignment="Center"  debería ser Stretch pero yo se lo quitaría y en su lugar agregaría Stretch="UniformToFill", otra opción si no lo elimino sería cambiarlo a Stretch y agregarle HorizontalAligment como Stretch igualmente. Intenté recrear tu proyecto pero faltan algunas partes así que no logro compilarlo.

Comment: Hola, el proyecto completo lo tengo en github https://github.com/davidgmd/Proyecto-de-fin-de-grado, para probar el funcionamiento, al ejecutar la aplicación, se introduce un usuario, por ejemplo english passw english, recursos de campaña o campaign resources y ahí estan los elementos, en el proyecto en View->CampaignResources->Menu recursos, y el UC esta en Resources->UserControls->CampaignResources->ElementoRecursos, he probado la solución que me propones pero no funciona creo que el problema debería ser aplicar un stretch al grid o al botón que lo contiene.